# What's going on in this pattern match?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

in Data.List, I saw this unfamiliar pattern match:

```
{-# NOINLINE [1] unsafeTake #-}
unsafeTake :: Int -> [a] -> [a] 
unsafeTake !_  []     = []
unsafeTake 1   (x: _) = [x]
unsafeTake m   (x:xs) = x : unsafeTake (m - 1) xs
```

My understanding is that `!` removes thunks. Okay, but `_` is ignored. There's something I'm not understanding. Clarification is appreciated.

Comment: Unrelated: I find the name `unsafeTake` ... peculiar, since it's not really that unsafe. Compared with `take`, `unsafeTake` will misbehave on negative integer argument (possibly diverging on infinite lists). Further, the library `take` never calls it with an unevaluated thunk making the bang pattern not _strictly_ necessary (pun intended).

Comment: @chi A case for the annotation here, would be if `unsafeTake` was exported from GHC.List, then it makes sense, but it isn't.

Comment: @EdgarKlerks True. The annotation might also be used as a hint to the optimizer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a [BangPattern](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.2/docs/html/users_guide/bang-patterns.html). It is a annotation to tell the compiler, that this function should behave strict in its first argument. It is equivalent to the following code:

```
unsafeTake :: Int -> [a] -> [a] 
unsafeTake x  []     = x `seq` []
unsafeTake 1   (x: _) = [x]
unsafeTake m   (x:xs) = m `seq` (x : unsafeTake (m - 1) xs)
```

And that the field is strict, means that if the first argument happens to be bottom, then the program halts:

```
unsafeTake (error "kaboom") []
```

This will throw kaboom with the strictness annotation, but it won't happen if it doesn't have it.

You can also place Bang Patterns into data type definitions:

```
data Tree a = Branch (Tree a) !a (Tree a)
            | Empty
```

Then it will always evaluate the field containing **a** to its weak head normal form. This means that it won't evaluate the whole structure. From the [haskell wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Weak_head_normal_form)

- a constructor (eventually applied to arguments) like True, Just (square 42) or (:) 1
- a built-in function applied to too few arguments (perhaps none) like (+) 2 or sqrt.
- or a lambda abstraction \x -> expression.

Comment: The translation is kind of correct, but not really. In the bang pattern version, `x` will be evaluated even if the second argument isn't `[]`. It doesn't matter much in this case because the second equation evaluates the first argument anyways.

Comment: But in the case that the second argument is the empty list, it won't happen. I guess the bang pattern is added here for the sake of consistency. It is weird that `unsafeTake (error "bla") [1,2,3,4,5]` blows up, but `unsafeTake (error "bla") []` doesn't.

Ah wait, I see, it reads now as if the bang pattern is the sole reason that the first argument gets evaluated, that is nonsense of course.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was: the first equation `unsafeTake !_  [] = []` means the first argument will always be evaluated, regardless of the rest of the equations and whether the second argument is `[]` or not. The first equation `unsafeTake x [] = x \`seq\` []` only forces `x` when the second argument is `[]`.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that. Thanks for the pointer,  I will update the answer!

Comment: I always annotated all the equations, so I can drop that habit too :)

Answer (score 0):

It tells the compiler that even if the second argument is `[]`, while it then knows it can apply the first alternative, it should still evaluate the first argument to head normal form. This means that `unsafeTake` is 'strict' in its first argument.

You can see the result if you try to evaluate `unsafeTake (last (repeat 0)) []` compared to the same with `take`.